# Variable isn't reading in correctly when i use getline( )

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple address book practice program for a c++ text book i have. For some reason when i try to store text to string with getline(cin, variablename, '\n') it doesn't store anything.

I am compiling with the g++ compiler on Linux mint 17.1
Any help is greatly appreciated .

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct peopleData
{
    string name;
    string address;
    string phoneNumber;
};

using namespace std;


peopleData getData (string name, string address, string phoneNumber)
{
    peopleData person;
    person.name = name;
    person.address = address;
    person.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    return person;
}


int main ()
{
    int amount_of_people;
    string name;
    string address;
    string phoneNumber;

    cout << "How many people are you entering information for? ";
    cin >> amount_of_people;

    peopleData people[amount_of_people];

    for ( int i = 0; i < amount_of_people; i++)
    {
        cout << "What is person " << i + 1 << "'s name?\n";
        getline( cin, name, '\n' );
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "What is " << name << "'s address?\n";
        getline( cin, address, '\n' );
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "What is ";
        cout << name << "'s phone number?\n";
        getline( cin, phoneNumber, '\n' );
        cin.ignore();
        people[i] = getData(name, address, phoneNumber); 
    }

    cout << "Your address book is finished.\n";
    for ( int x = 0; x < amount_of_people; x++)
    {
        cout << people[x].name 
             << "'s address is "  << people[x].address 
             << "\nand their phone number is " << people[x].phoneNumber << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not going to follow that link! [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please!

Comment: Would you rather i post it in the post?

Comment: _"Would you rather i post it in the post?"_ No! Not unless it's a minimal sample.

Comment: Why do you think the `std::getline()` is not working, did you do anything to prove that is what is failing (like print out the variable)?

Comment: Yes, when I print out the variable, its completely blank

Comment: I would try `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` first.

Comment: [It almost works for me](http://ideone.com/9t3J7m). I think you should remove the `cin.ignore();` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so update: you should be calling cin.ignore() BEFORE getline and not after getline. If you want to do it your current way, you forgot to call cin.ignore() after you read the number, causing the first one to appear completely empty.

The previous answer was wrong, but the following statement still holds true:

Your '\n' is redundant. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. I'm extremely new to programming, so I apologize if this seemed stupid. Edit: I tried adding in the & signs and it won't compile.

Comment: @d3crypt You just forget about this, it's blatant nonsense.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not anymore.

Comment: Yep, I realized that almost immediately, which is why I edited the post explaining that its is wrong. I've updated the answer, and it works for me now (g++ os x)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Let's say I've noticed that, and leave as a reminder for Rahul (I didn't downvote).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to ignore the rest of line after

   ```
   cin >> amount_of_people;
   ```

   Add the following right after the above line:

   ```
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   ```
2. Remove the calls to `cin.ignore();` after the calls to `getline()`. `getline()` consumes the `'\n'` from the stream but does not add it to the output string.